# Capitalization of Attorney General Office

Tags: capitalization

I understand that "attorney general" by itself should not be capitalized but capitalizing attorney general should be done if it is accompanied by a name (e.g., Attorney General Stewart).  But how about the actual office.  Should "office of the attorney general" be capitalized as "Office of the Attorney General?"  Bureau of Alcohol, or Department of Homeland Security, if I'm not mistaken, are capitalized, so I would assume Office of the Attorney General would also be capitalized.

Answer (score 1):

If that is the actual proper name of the office, then you would write "Attorney General Office."

HOWEVER, if it isn't the actual proper name, or even if you don't know if it is, then you wouldn't write "Attorney General Office."  But you wouldn't write "attorney general office," either.  You'd instead "attorney general's office," the possessive "-'s" denoting the "of" in your phrase "office of the attorney general."

Comment: Thank you - I think the way I have my sentence written, it SHOULD NOT be capitalized as I don't believe I am using it as a proper name in my sentence.

Comment: The state law enforcement agencies also include the office of the attorney general, Department of Justice, Bureau of Narcotic Enforcement, Bureau of Gambling Control, and Bureau of Firearms.

Comment: I would capitalize it there.